# SQL Server 2012 Change Data Capture Performance

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

I've been running CDC for about a week. I have SSIS packages that run daily to load the changes into a staging database.

Until yesterday, the SSIS packages have been completing in about 5 minutes.  Now the process will run for hours. It hangs on the CDC Source Task, which is set to capture net changes. This step appears to call

```
cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance>
```

This function will run for hours. It's not always the same `capture_instance`.

What would cause the sudden performance degradation?

Comment: Do you have SP2?  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2989478

Comment: I ran across the performance bug during development.  I applied the hotfix to my dev environment and it appeared to resolve the issue.  Prior to releasing to production, I applied the hotfix to the production environments.  Everything seemed fine until yesterday.  I'm going to adjust the retention period to see if it has any effect.